# Python Web Scraping cannot extract table data I wanted

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is what I am trying to accomplish from the page https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/native?cursor=15297&filter=asset-holders

1. extract the data in the table columns (Account and Account balance)
2. write the extracted data fields into a text file.
3. I am trying to extract multiple pages like from 15297 to 15500.

I am still very new to python and web scraping and I had been struggling to get the desired output. Help will be very appreciated. Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    import urllib.request as urllib2
except ImportError:
    import urllib2
from time import sleep

url = 'https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/native?cursor=15297&filter=asset-holders'
page = urllib2.urlopen((url))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'table exportable space'}):
    address = div.find('tbody', attrs={'class': "account-address"})
    address = address.text.strip() 
    print (address)

    bal = div.find('tbody', attrs={'class': "text-right nowrap"})
    bal = bal.text.strip() 
    print (balance)
print ("%s%s\n" % ("page=", str(URL)))
```

Output I wanted to get written to (result.txt):

```
 GBMN2KIUQS66JMJHVOCA7N3S35F4F5PTY63XG3BJKKDMLPI4HPHA7QNU: 27,005 XLM
 GBWVMIVJQNILFPHACV4Q7QM7VBOOQ35IQXEOOXO7WBXA4KX7OEADOU65: 27,004 XLM
 GD3UXDHKS5EIKSL3PIG3NTVCCK5EQX73JMFJBFBROX3BAZ4K6437TZAC: 27,003 XLM
 GBYUHMDQYNNDMJWOVODTZUKWOTVJXA2PCTDOF6J5NQS5DGMMJAL6B66L: 27,002 XLM
 GDD3AQFXWWHWEFAOU4AWPZCT3Q6EVK4WYHWSG2EBQB3Z43KZSXJEK6WB: 27,001 XLM
```

Comment: The page is loaded with javascript you can inspect the page and see if they have an api, if so make the request for it. Another way out would be to use selenium

Comment: The correct term is ‘scraping’. Scrapping means throwing away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this code snippet can help you.

I inspected the web page and saw that they use an api, made a request for it and was returned the data you want and the links to the next and the previous page:

```
import requests

header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:86.0Gecko/20100101 Firefox/86.0'}
req = requests.get(url='https://api.stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/XLM/holders?cursor=15297&filter=asset-holders&limit=50&order=asc', headers=header)

print(f"Previous page: {req.json()['_links']['prev']['href']}")
print(f"Next page: {req.json()['_links']['next']['href']}")

for dict_ in req.json()['_embedded']['records']:
    print(dict_['account'], dict_['balance'])
```

You can also access the url in your browser to see the data

Comment: Thank you. I just dont know how to get the data I wanted into a text file though with this approach.

Comment: A more detailed snippet would be helpful as I am really struggling to make this work.

Comment: I edited the answer, see if you can now see the data. Good luck in your studies.

Comment: I tried this approach and its very very fast. Thank you very very much for the snippet. This helps me a lot..

Comment: can you help me on something scraping poocoin.app/ape. I tried using the snippet you have but Im at lost. I wanted to write into text file all the two columns(Token, Creation Time).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to scrape dynamically rendered content.  For this you could look into using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html).  For this solution to work in particular you will need to go to [this link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and download and install a **WebDriver** called geckodriver and make it available in your path.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib
import time

START_RANK = 15297
END_RANK = 15500

current_rank = START_RANK

file_name = 'result.txt'
base_url = 'stellar.expert'
path = 'explorer/public/asset/native'

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    while current_rank <= END_RANK:
        query_params = {'cursor': str(current_rank), 'filter': 'asset-holders'}
    
        driver.get('https://{0}/{1}?{2}'.format(base_url, path, 
            '&'.join(f'{k}={v}' for k, v in query_params.items())))

        # this is just to ensure that the page is loaded 
        time.sleep(10)  

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

        table = soup.find('table', {'class': ['table', 'exportable', 'space']})
        tbody = table.find('tbody')
    
        for trow in tbody.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
            pubkey = trow.find('span', attrs={'class': 'account-pubkey'})
            balance = trow.find('span', attrs={'class': ['amount', 'nowrap']})
            
            print(pubkey.text, balance.text, file=f)

            current_rank += 1
            if current_rank > END_RANK: break
```

Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
bs4 = "*"
selenium = "*"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this approach. Installed Selenium and webdriver. Running exactly the same code you have and got the error:                                                                   
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python38\Stellar Scapper.py", line 25, in <module> tbody = table.find('tbody') AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: I checked on my end and compare the packages. The only difference is my chardet==3.0.4. All the rest are the same as yours. Im running python 3.8 though.

Comment: I've added the PIpfile above if you want to create a virtual environment using pipenv to check my solution

Comment: Thank you. I got it working by modifying this part - tbody = soup.find('tbody'). How can I make the script to run from 15297 to let us say 15500?
https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/native?cursor=15297&filter=asset-holders - https://stellar.expert/explorer/public/asset/native?cursor=15500&filter=asset-holders

Comment: This will require you to update the cursor in the query string of the url and make another request.  I've refactored my original solution to make additional requests.

Comment: I tried running for multiple pages and I got the error after 4 or sometimes 6 pages. Im not sure what is the problem. The error is- for trow in tbody.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: I ran into a similar problem when debugging.  I think there are two possible cases to consider: (1) the content hasn't loaded yet, and (2) there are no more items to read (i.e. the cursor number exceeds the maximum rank).  Either way, you can handle the first error by adding a try-except block and make another request, the second case can be handled by checking if any records were retrieved.

Comment: I think the problem is unstable internet connection.

Comment: That may have something to do with it.  I would suggest adding a try-except block that repeats the request 2-3 times, each time increasing the number of seconds to sleep before raising an exception.

Comment: I dont know how to add a try except to check if there is an internet connection.